# How to change passive tree tab view settings in Path of Exile?

Tags: path-of-exile

In many youtube videos, you can see players opening their passive tree tab and have it centered on either the same spot they last closed the tree or the last node they added rather than simply centered on the passive tree center. It is mostly apparent in speed runs where adding nodes needs to be a quick thing.

How is this achieved?

Thank you!

Comment: I've asked myself the same thing and I think it is based on if you have closed the game/changed character in between. But I'm not sure, I could test tonight, but need to work for 4 more hours first.

Comment: Seems like I was wrong, I have no idea in that case.

Answer (score 3):

After trying around for a while I discovered that two things are saved for as long as you stay logged in on a character:

- Zoom level
- Mini-skill tree of ascendancy class being open or not.

They will default to zoomed in as much as possible with ascendancy skill tree open on selecting a character. The location of where exactly you were looking is never saved, and always resets to your characters starting position in the grid.

In speed runs, the players probably zoom out as much as possible since they know where all the nodes they need are, and thus it looks like it stays like they left it.